# Landscape splash screen not loading

Tags: ios, cordova, screen, splash-screen

I have a phonegap application with splash screens in my project/resources/splash/ directory. My iOS project loads the portrait splash screen fine, but when I load the app in landscape mode, it uses my portrait splash screen then I get a white screen after the splash screen loads.

I've realized that in my log it keeps saying `the splashscreen image named Default-Landscape was not found`, even though I've renamed my landscape images in /splash/ directory to Default-Landscape.jpg it seems like it is not pulling the image.

[image]

Any insight as to how I can get this working? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

This has been a confirmed bug in the previous versions but now has been fixed. Try using this:

```
<gap:splash src="splash-xlarge-portrait.png" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi">
<gap:splash src="splash-xlarge-landscape.png" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi">
<icon src="icon-xlarge-english.png" gap:qualifier="en-xhdpi">
<icon src="icon-xlarge-french.png" gap:qualifier="fr-xhdpi">
<icon src="icon.png" gap:qualifier="">
```

For iOS:

```
<!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
<splash src="Default.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<splash src="Default@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash src="Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

<!-- iPad -->
<splash src="Default-Portrait.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash src="Default-Landscape.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

<!-- Retina iPad -->
<splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Is this for iOS? I know I've used port-xhdpi and land-xhdpi for android. My config.xml looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/VJdxc

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm still seeing the error even though I've renamed the images to .png as well as added the lines in my config.xml. Also did a clean and rebuild. Have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it the same error that you mentioned above? Have you built it again and then tried to run? Check the path of the image that you're adding.

Comment: Yep. I've tried a clean and rebuild. I tried one with no path and then another with my standard res/screen/ios/ -- it is in resources/splash but I thought it should be res/screen/ios.. the splash screen still pulls my normal portrait splash screen.

Comment: Copy splash screen images into the iOS project's Resources/splash directory. For more information refer this document: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html

Comment: Yep, they are currently there. I assume when you did <splash src="Default the default path is resources/splash? I tried that but still seems to not grab the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125455/discussion-between-chiragh-dewan-and-chronotrigga).